# Save complex object to session ASP .NET CORE 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core

I am quite new to ASP .NET core, so please help. I would like to avoid database round trip for ASP .NET core application. I have functionality to dynamically add columns in datagrid. Columns settings (visibility, enable, width, caption) are stored in DB.

So I would like to store **List<,PersonColumns>** **on server** only for actual session. But I am not able to do this. I already use JsonConvert methods to serialize and deserialize objects to/from session. This works for **List<,Int32>** or objects with simple properties, but not for complex object with nested properties.

My  object I want to store to session looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
  public class PersonColumns
  {
    public Int64 PersonId { get; set; }
    List<ViewPersonColumns> PersonCols { get; set; }

    public PersonColumns(Int64 personId)
    {
      this.PersonId = personId;
    }

    public void LoadPersonColumns(dbContext dbContext)
    {
      LoadPersonColumns(dbContext, null);
    }

    public void LoadPersonColumns(dbContext dbContext, string code)
    {
      PersonCols = ViewPersonColumns.GetPersonColumns(dbContext, code, PersonId);
    } 

    public static List<ViewPersonColumns> GetFormViewColumns(SatisDbContext dbContext, string code, Int64 formId, string viewName, Int64  personId)
    {
      var columns = ViewPersonColumns.GetPersonColumns(dbContext, code, personId);

      return columns.Where(p => p.FormId == formId && p.ObjectName == viewName).ToList();
    }


  }
```

I would like to ask also if my approach is not bad to save the list of 600 records to session? Is it better to access DB and load columns each time user wants to display the grid?

Any advice appreciated

Thanks

**EDIT**: I have tested to store in session **List<,ViewPersonColumns>** and it is correctly saved. When I save object where the **List<,ViewPersonColumns>** is property, then only **built-in types** are saved, List property is null.

**The object I want to save in session**

```
[Serializable]
  public class UserManagement
  {
    public String PersonUserName { get; set; }
    public Int64 PersonId { get; set; }
    public List<ViewPersonColumns> PersonColumns { get; set; } //not saved to session??

    public UserManagement() { }

    public UserManagement(DbContext dbContext, string userName)
    {
      var person = dbContext.Person.Single(p => p.UserName == userName);

      PersonUserName = person.UserName;
      PersonId = person.Id;
    }

    /*public void PrepareUserData(DbContext dbContext)
    {
      LoadPersonColumns(dbContext);
    }*/

    public void LoadPersonColumns(DbContext dbContext)
    {
      LoadPersonColumns(dbContext, null);
    }

    public void LoadPersonColumns(DbContext dbContext, string code)
    {
      PersonColumns = ViewPersonColumns.GetPersonColumns(dbContext, code, PersonId);
    }

    public List<ViewPersonColumns> GetFormViewColumns(Int64 formId, string viewName)
    {
      if (PersonColumns == null)
        return null;

      return PersonColumns.Where(p => p.FormId == formId && p.ObjectName == viewName).ToList();
    }

  }
```

**Save columns to the session**

```
UserManagement userManagement = new UserManagement(_context, user.UserName);
userManagement.LoadPersonColumns(_context);
HttpContext.Session.SetObject("ActualPersonContext", userManagement);
HttpContext.Session.SetObject("ActualPersonColumns", userManagement.PersonColumns);
```

**Load columns from the session**

```
//userManagement build-in types are set. The PersonColumns is null - not correct
UserManagement userManagement = session.GetObject<UserManagement>("ActualPersonContext");
//The cols is filled from session with 600 records - correct
List<ViewPersonColumns> cols = session.GetObject<List<ViewPersonColumns>>("ActualPersonColumns");
```

Answer (score 9):

Use list for each column is better than use database.
you can't create and store sessions in .net core like .net framework 4.0

Try Like this

**Startup.cs**

```js
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddDbContext<GeneralDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));        

            services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
            services.AddSession();
        }
```

**Common/SessionExtensions.cs**

```js
sing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IMAPApplication.Common
{
    public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        public static T GetComplexData<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var data = session.GetString(key);
            if (data == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
        }

        public static void SetComplexData(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

- ==> Create Session*

```js
public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
        {               
          LoggedUserVM user = GetUserDataById(model.userId);   
          
          //Create Session with complex object   
          HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData("loggerUser", user);         
                
          return Json(new { status = result.Status, message = result.Message });              

        }
```

- ==> Get Session data*

```js
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //Get Session data     
            LoggedUserVM loggedUser = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<LoggedUserVM>("loggerUser");                         
        }
```

Hope this is helpful. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I thing that I had it almost same, only difference was that I did not use services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider(); and I used services.AddDistributedMemoryCache. Actually do not know what is difference. But if you could see my edit, I make it works somehow, but it is more workaround then solution for me :) As I want only one session key for whole user object.

Comment: By default, `TempData` uses cookies exclusively to persist date to the next request. Adding `AddSessionStateTempDataProvider`, uses `Session` to handle `TempData` instead. It has nothing really to do with what you've got going on here. By the same token, `AddDistributedMemoryCache` is only tangentially related, as `Session` uses the distributed cache provider under the hood. This line is essentially saying that you're going to use in memory cache, which therefore means your `Session` will be in memory too. However, that's the default *anyways*, so you can remove that.

Comment: It's great that you did it some how.If you take my answer, please mark it as answer.It'll help other to find.. :)

Comment: Nice extension methods!

Answer (score 2):

This is an evergreen post, and even though Microsoft has recommended serialisation to store the object in session - it is not a correct solution unless your object is readonly, I have a blog explaining all scenario [here](https://technologymythbuster.blogspot.com/2020/01/storing-objects-in-session-in-aspnet.html) and i have even pointed out the issues in GitHub of Asp.Net Core in issue id [18159](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18159)

**Synopsis of the problems are here:**

A. Serialisation isn't same as object, true it will help in distributed server scenario but it comes with a **caveat** that Microsoft have failed to highlight - that it will work without any unpredictable failures only when the object is meant to be read and not to be written back.

B. If you were looking for a read-write object in the session, everytime you change the object that is read from the session after deserialisation - it needs to be written back to the session again by calling serialisation - and this alone can lead to multiple complexities as you will need to either keep track of the changes - or keep writing back to session after each change in any property. In one request to the server, you will have scenarios where the object is written back multiple times till the response is sent back.

C. For a read-write object in the session, even on a single server it will fail, as the actions of the user can trigger multiple rapid requests to the server and not more than often system will find itself in a situation where the object is being serialised or deserialised by one thread and being edited and then written back by another, the result is you will end up with overwriting the object state by threads - and even locks won't help you much since the object is not a real object but a temporary object created by deserialisation.

D. There are issues with serialising complex objects - it is not just a performance hit, it may even fail in certain scenario - especially if you have deeply nested objects that sometimes refer back to itself.

**The synopsis of the solution is here**, full implementation along with code is in the blog [link](https://technologymythbuster.blogspot.com/2020/01/storing-objects-in-session-in-aspnet.html):

1. First implement this as a Cache object, create one item in IMemoryCache for each unique session.
2. Keep the cache in sliding expiration mode, so that each time it is read it revives the expiry time - thereby keeping the objects in cache as long as the session is active.
3. Second point alone is not enough, you will need to implement heartbeat technique - triggering the call to session every T minus 1 min or so from the javascript. (This we anyways used to do even to keep the session alive till the user is working on the browser, so it won't be any different

**Additional Recommendations**

A. Make an object called SessionManager - so that all your code related to session read / write sits in one place.

B. Do not keep very high value for session time out - If you are implementing heartbeat technique, even 3 mins of session time out will be enough.

Comment: It really is a nightmare (performance, etc.) to always serialize object(s) and updating session, jesus Microsoft.